# Download all files with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to download all the images and annotations from this link: https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/pwyyg8zmk5/2

For example, I want to download all the images in the bicycle folder. Then there's a download button for each image file. I tried to do this with selenium this way (Xpath="//a[@aria-label='Download file']"), but it only downloads the first image, how can I download all of them? Is it possible with selenium?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/pwyyg8zmk5/2")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Bicycle']")
    
folder.click()

folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='images']")
folder.click()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Download file']")
folder.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try this:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver= webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/pwyyg8zmk5/2")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Bicycle']")
    
folder.click()

folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='images']")
folder.click()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
d_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Download file']")
for d in d_list:
    d.click()
    d_list.extend([a for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Download file']") if a not in d_list])
```

First, note that I used *find_element**s**_by_xpath* instead of *find_element_by_xpath*, it returns a list of **every html element** that matches with `//a[@aria-label='Download file']`.

That list is incomplete because the page only shows the first *21* results at first, that's why you must add this code in the loop:

```
d_list.extend([a for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Download file']") if a not in d_list])
```

It finds new images when you make new clicks to download the images(because it will scroll down the html element).

Comment: It downloads the first 22 images, and then gives this error:
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

Comment: can you try to run it again?

Comment: It can happen if you manipulate the page when the script is running.

Comment: It downloaded upto the file bicycle (12).jpg from the start. I've just started selenium today, so I'm having a hard time to figure it out.

Comment: Though, If you just want to download images from that page, I've to recommend you to find the relevant requests to do that, for example: https://data.mendeley.com/public-api/datasets/pwyyg8zmk5/files/?folder_id=84b1e3af-7263-4381-86f5-ecccb98abd23&version=2

Comment: Yes, it downloaded everything now, the issue was I was scrolling the window and I think only the first 21 images were showing at first before being automatically scrolled

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
x=0
while True:
  x+=1
  try:
    folder= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/article/section[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div["+str(x)+"]/a/svg")
    folder.click()
  except:
    pass
```